# How to print out symbols assigned via the .size directive in GNU Assembler

Tags: c, assembly, gnu-assembler

I have the following assembly code

```
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    $5, %esi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
```

Rather than print out 5, I want to print out the space between my current location and my first function (named func), I've been trying the following:

```
var1:
    .long .-func
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    var1, %esi  
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
```

And I've tried

```
.size var1, .-func
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    movl    var1, %esi  
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf@PLT
```

Nothing I've tried has worked so far, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
var1:
    .long .-func
```

will make an object whose value is the distance between it and `func`. As I understand your question, you want the distance between the point of the call in main and `func`. So something like:

```
leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
movl    $.-func, %esi  
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf@PLT
```

Instead of `.`, you could use a label for a particular instruction in `main`, if needed.

The `.size` directive has nothing to do with what you want, although it's a common place you may have seen the `.-symbol` idiom. Its only purposes are debugging/disassembly assistance, making `dladdr` identify symbols that addresses belong to correctly, and (for data) making copy relocations work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the size of a symbol as set with the `.size` directive.  It's for debugging and some special cases involving common data areas only.  To set `var1` to `.-func1`, you can write

```
.set var1, .-func
```

This should work.  Your second example should work, too.  But without knowing what you expect it to do instead of what it is doing right now, that's hard to say.

Comment: Thanks works! Thank you. I could not get my second answer to work! According to the manual it should work...may I wasn't using the proper syntax.

Comment: @mautiemunda Did you get any error?  What makes you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, when I tried to upvote you it said I needed 15 reputation. when trying to use ```skip symbol, expression``` directive I get a relocation error against whichever section the skip directive is used.